# Using generics to convert an object to a dictionary

Tags: generics, swift4, swift-protocols

I'm trying to generate a Dictionary like `["title": "a string", "id": 1]` from objects. I have two objects customers and suppliers. I would like to have a method like

```
func getDict<T>(values: [T]) -> [String: Any] {
    for value in values {
        value 
        // I don't know how to say sometime 
        // id is value.idSupplier or
        // sometime value.idCustommer
        // Same problem for title.
     }
}
```

An exemple of objects (simplify version):

```
struct Customer {
    var idCustomer: Int
    var name: String?
}

struct Supplier {
    var idSupplier: Int
    var name: String?
}
```

Is there a way to achieve that or maybe I misunderstood generics ?

Comment: @vadian from my objects, values types, I'm updating my question with an exemple. It's my problem, how to get key in a generic way

Comment: I wrote an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that unless you are writing a lot of  boilerplate code but then you got no benefit over an `if - else` clause.

If the property names `id` and `name` are the same in both structs you could use a protocol extension

```
protocol ToDictionary {
    var id : Int { get }
    var name : String? { get }
}

extension ToDictionary {
    var dictionaryRepresentation : [String : Any] {
        return ["title" : name ?? "", "id" : id]
    }
}
```

Then adopt the protocol in both structs

```
struct Customer : ToDictionary {
    var id: Int
    var name: String?
}

struct Supplier : ToDictionary {
    var id: Int
    var name: String?
}
```

Now you can call `dictionaryRepresentation` in any struct which adopts the protocol

```
let customer = Customer(id: 1, name: "Foo")
customer.dictionaryRepresentation // ["id": 1, "title": "Foo"]
let supplier = Supplier(id: 2, name: "Bar")
supplier.dictionaryRepresentation // ["id": 2, "title": "Bar"]
```

---

Alternatively use the `Codable` protocol, encode the instances to JSON or Property List and then convert them to dictionary.

Comment: Not the answer I expect but I understand, thanks for your help!